# How to debug MPJExpress locally in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, mpj-express

For eclipse there is an extension available to set debug configurations for MPJExpress.
How I can debug an application locally in IntelliJ IDEA.
I've tried to set up debugging using vm options in run/debug configurations. With this configuration I get message given below and breakpoint does not get a hit.

> MPJ Express (0.44) is started in the multicore configuration
>
> Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8001

vm options are

`-jar $MPJ_HOME$\lib\starter.jar com.owiSoft.Lab6.HelloMPJ -np 4 -device niodev  -debug 8001`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to debug this MPJExpress application by modifying vm optios from

`-jar $MPJ_HOME$\lib\starter.jar com.owiSoft.Lab6.HelloMPJ -np 4 -device niodev  -debug 8001`

to

`-jar $MPJ_HOME$\lib\starter.jar com.owiSoft.Lab6.HelloMPJ -np 4 -debug 8000`

And added another Remote configuration from Run/Debug Configurations menu

[image]

Then started Main configuration, kept it running and switched to `RemoteDebugger` configuration and started it. Following these steps breakpoint got a hit

Answer (score 0):

MPJ Express provides Eclipse Plugin to Execute and Debug MPJ Express Applications in Eclipse. This plugin is very easy to use and do not require different sets commands to remember. Step wise Tutorial and video guides for plugin are provided at MPJExpress website. [MPJ Express User Guides and Tutorials](http://mpjexpress.org/guides.html)

In case somebody directly wants to jump at debugging part without plugin. Follow [this youtube tutorial starting from 04:00](https://youtu.be/ROXFfUbgY98?t=3m59s).

Comment: Yes @aleem. I've viewed that video and tutorials as well. But I wanted to configure it with IntelliJ IDEA. I was able to achieve that by following the steps given in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000719/3358570) below.